# vue-router- way to persist query param from old route to new route

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

For every route in my application, if there's a certain query param, let's call it `userId`,  I would like the next route to also contain that query param.

One solution is to modify every `router-link` and `router.push` to add this query param, but I'd like to use `router.beforeEach` to solve this problem.

I tried this, but it starts an infinite loop:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (from.query.userId) {
    next({
      path: to.path,
      query: Object.assign({}, to.query, from.query.userId),
    })
  }
  next()
})
```

Is there any way in vue-router that allows me to persist a query param if it exists in the previous route?

Comment: sounds like you might be better off using Dynamic Route Matching: https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/dynamic-matching.html

Comment: i don't, "userid" is really not a user of our app, its strictly for tracking purposes and has nothing to do with the page itself.

Comment: why are you using :
query: Object.assign({}, to.query, from.query.userId), 
 but not just 
query: from.query  
?

Comment: He Andrew, did you ever find a solution? 
I'm having the same issue with Vue 3

Answer (score 1):

I was stumbling across the same problem and here is my production solution:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    let requiresAuth = (to.meta.hasOwnProperty('requiresAuth') ? to.meta.requiresAuth : true);

    //... comment
    if (!store.getters.isAuthenticated() && requiresAuth) {
        next({name: 'login', params: {...{redirect: to.name}, ...to.params}});
        return;
    } else if (store.getters.isAuthenticated() && !store.getters.isDataPreloaded() && to.name !== 'preloading') {
        //... comment
        next({name: 'preloading', params: {...{redirect: to.name}, ...to.params}});
        return;
    }

    next();
})
```

It doesn't matter what you use - query or params. Don't forget that you can use optional parameters to tell while redirecting that something is happening. You can add an optional `param` like `redirected` and check it in your `beforeEach` method, if it is set to true - perform one action, if it is set to false - perform another action.

Remember that with `params` property you can exchange between routes with absolutely any data (JS objects) you want without showing this data to your users in URLs.

Let me explain why and how my code works:

1. User opens a page `example.com/my-private-zone/dashboard/reports`
2. System checks if he is already authenticated, if not - save `from` route and redirect to `login` page - `example.com/login`.
3. User authenticates
4. User is being redirected to `preloading` page (`example.com/preloading`) where all the needed JS scripts are preloaded.
5. User is being redirected to the route from the 0-step. As you can see I am `passing` the user entry point (as `redirect` param) for the final redirect without changing URL that is being displayed to a user.

Your code also *should be* fine, you forgot to add a `return` statement in your `if` branch:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (from.query.userId) {
    next({
      path: to.path,
      query: Object.assign({}, to.query, from.query.userId),
    })
    return;
  }
  next()
})
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Tried out above block of code, resulted in same infinite loop error